# Why is my rails model returning nil for a nonexistent entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I have a very simple RoR web app that tracks calories. I have it setup so that a user enters their calories and the date and it saves it to the database. I then display the recorded data back to the user in a table.

However, I kept getting this error: `undefined method 'strftime' for nil:NilClass`. What's strange though, is that it's giving this error for a (from what I can see) nonexistent entry.

As a temporary solution, I've thrown in an if statement to display a '?' if the data is nil. I can't see why the model is returning nil though. I've tried resetting the database so that it's empty and I'm still getting a nil.

Here is a link to my app's repository: https://github.com/barhamd/simple_calorie_tracker

The model that tracks the calories and date is named "tracker", and the view that displays this data is located at `/app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just use Rails Debugger, it helps you to find the issue. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `StaticPagesController`, line 4, you should have:

```
@tracker = Tracker.new
```

since this is the new model you're building the form for. On create you're saving the tracker to the current_user anyway.

Otherwise you're also iterating over this new model in `current_user.trackers.each do` which prints all the nil values.